# Retrieve data from Field API programmatically

Tags: 7, entities

I have a custom field called phone_number for the user. I need to retrieve the data in it from the database and use it to call other functions. I've looked through the Field API and I can't find the specific function. I read somewhere in the Field Attach API that most of the functions there take $entity as a variable but none of the functions there gives me what I need. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions: use Entity API (http://drupal.org/project/entity) and create an object wrapper around the entity and just $phone = $wrapper->phone_field.

Or use the field_extract module (http://drupal.org/project/1158878) which provides two functions for extracting data from Field API fields.

Or third, code it yourself, but you don't want to do that.

(I wrote the field_extract module so I am biased.)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Field data extraction](http://drupal.org/project/1158878) API module to accomplish your job of field data extraction.

As per the documentation, you have to write this in yourmodule

```
  $phonenumbers = field_extract_values('node', $node, 'phone_number');

  $result = someCustomFunction($phonenumbers);

  function someCustomFunction($user_phonenumbers){

   // Do something here and return value

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The entities already loads a field data. if you have attached some fields to user you can use this as $user->myfield but sometimes in my practice field data has not appered. In that case you can load a entity load functions like node_load() or user_load()